# Comparing modelled time series with observed time series, Davidson & MacKinnon

Tags: regression, time-series, model-selection, simulation, model-comparison

I have a simulation model with several producers in which I vary an assumption concerning market structure (Cournot or competitive). The outcome of this model is a time series of prices. I am interested in the question whether historical prices can be better explained by Cournot or competitive behavior of the producers. Hence, in total, I have 3 time series: modelled prices with the competitive assumption, modelled prices with the Cournot assumption and observed prices. I tried to follow a methodology based on Davidson & MacKinnon for comparing non-tested models, i.e. regressing observed data on a linear combination of both model alternatives:

Price_observed_t = A1 * Price_Cournot_t + A2 * Price_Competitive_t + U_t

Herby, I found that the coefficient associated with the Cournot model A1 was significant, whereas the coefficient associated with the competitive model A2 was insignificant for explaining the historical prices. However, I could reject the null hypothesis A1=1, A2=0. According to Davidson & MacKinnon, this hypothesis should not be rejected in order to claim consistency between the Cournot model and the observed data. Now, I am wondering if I can still conclude that that the Cournot model is a better indicator for explaining historical prices based on the fact that the coefficient A1 was significant? Besides this regression, I thought about additionally considering other measures like (adjusted) R_squared, Theil’s inequality coefficient and Spearman’s rank correlation for comparing the modelled time series and the observed time series.